# Glueviz Errorbars

Tags: python, errorbar, python-glue

I created a scatterplot in glueviz and now I want to include the errorbars. The corresponding errors are already calculated and listed in a column within my datafile.

So my file looks something like this:

```
| Planet | Mass | Mass_Error1 | Mass_Error2 | Radius | Radius_Error1 | Radius_Error 2 |
```

I am using Glueviz 0.14.1 with python 3.7.1 on Windows (if that matters)

Does anyone know how to do this? I looked through the already existing questions but did't find anything. Also in the documentation of Glue I didn't find an answer. Is it even possible to create errorbars with glueviz?

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

It's pretty easy: below the plot Layers you see "Color", "Points", "Line", "Errors" and "Vectors". Just click on Error and you can choose in which column of your dataset your errors for the x-Axis and the y-Axis are listet, and it automatically includes the errorbars.